# sqlite c# substr calls error

Tags: c#, sqlite, substr

The task is simple, there is a local DB, and an application, which searches through it and shows a table with results. The problem is with SQL query. I have 3 column in Classes table, and I need only 2 to be shown in app's table, and the second one should have restricted number of letters. SQLite SQL manager executes this query and gives me correct data, but c# gives me an error.

```
private void SearchButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        base_connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=New_test_base.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";
        base_connection.Open();
        sqlite_cmd= base_connection.CreateCommand();
        sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "select Tag, substr(Description, 1, 2) from Classes where Description = 'rty'";// "select * from Classes where Description = '"+ SearchString.Text+"'";

        DbData = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();


        DbData.Read();
            string myreader = DbData["Tag"].ToString()+DbData["Description"].ToString();

            MessageBox.Show(myreader);


    }
```

An error is: Index is out of massive array(not sure about wording, I have Russian VS)
I'm using System.Data.SQLite;

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to give column alias '`Description`' in your query.

```
private void SearchButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    base_connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=New_test_base.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;";
    base_connection.Open();
    sqlite_cmd= base_connection.CreateCommand();
    sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "select Tag, substr(Description, 1, 2) as Description from Classes where Description = 'rty'";// "select * from Classes where Description = '"+ SearchString.Text+"'";

    DbData = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DbData.Read();
    string myreader = DbData["Tag"].ToString()+DbData["Description"].ToString();

    MessageBox.Show(myreader);
}
```

Comment: This was going to be my suggestion, though I would probably use a different name for the alias (e.g. `DescripPrefix`) to avoid any issues should I ever want the whole description field as well. Depending how the classes work, accessing by position instead of name (e.g. `DbData[1]` or `DbData[2]` depending on where indexing starts) may also work.